# R doesn't open with UTF-8

Tags: r, unicode

I want to open R with input encoding UTF-8 for plots, and I can't seem to get it to work.

This is my (short) program in plot.R

```
plot(1:5, xlab="ř")
```

And this is what I get (I, sadly, have to use old version of R)

```
~/$ R <plot.R  --no-save --encoding="utf-8"

R version 2.8.0 (2008-10-20)
Copyright (C) 2008 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> plot(1:5, xlab="ř")
Warning messages:
1: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'ř' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <c5>
2: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'ř' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <99>
3: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'ř' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <c5>
4: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'ř' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <99>
>
```

Googling anything R-related is a daunting task, so I am asking here. Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just the old R version?

edit: it seems like the error is not in input encoding, but in something else - when I write the letter as `\u0159`, it does the same thing. So it is probably something with PDF fonts, I guess.

To reply to Joran: I don't really know the intricacies of R output devices; my R outputs by default into PDF. I have to use Fedora, release 8. (again, ancient, as well as the R version)

Comment: Works in 2.13.0 (Patched). These sorts of things depend on more than the R version though; often the details of your OS and the type of device you are plotting to (PDF, Postscript, etc.) matter quite a lot. The folks who will know the answer to this will likely want to know that information in order to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forced my admin to upgrade R and it works, but I needed to set up `Sys.setlocale` first.

That about answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

In R you generally need to spell things with proper upper and lowercase to each character, so you should try: "UTF-8"

Furthermore, I think UTF-8 is the default encoding for most European and North American systems, so why are you changing the default? I get no warnings with that code and character which looks like a lowercase r with a cupped "hat" on my system.

And R 2.8 is really ancient.

Searching: Use CRAN or r-project or language:r to limit your searching a bit, or go to [RSiteSearch](http://search.r-project.org/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=&max=20&result=normal&sort=score&idxname=functions&idxname=views) or [RSeek](http://www.rseek.org/). (I use [different defaults for Baron's search site](http://search.r-project.org/cgi-bin/namazu.cgi?query=&max=100&result=normal&sort=score&idxname=Rhelp10&idxname=Rhelp08&idxname=Rhelp02&idxname=functions).)

Comment: Thanks for the searching tips!

Comment: The character is correct. As I found out, the problem is more with the PDF device. Probably some fonts missing or something.

Comment: This is a pretty common problem. Try `pdf.options()$encoding`.