# R plot title encoding in Pdf

Tags: r, encoding, plot

This question is related to: [Rhtml: Warning: conversion failure on '<var>' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <var>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251665/rhtml-warning-conversion-failure-on-var-in-mbcstosbcs-dot-substituted-f) and [R doesn't open with UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637989/r-doesnt-open-with-utf-8)

I use Ubuntu, I can not show a turkish character, `ı`, on the title of a plot:

`myScript.r`:

```
pdf(file='/home/sait/Desktop/abc.pdf')
plot(1:7,1:7,main='geziparkı')
```

I am having the following warning messages when I run the script using `Rscript myScript.r`,

```
Warning messages:
1: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'geziparkı' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <c4>
2: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'geziparkı' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b1>
3: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'geziparkı' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <c4>
4: In title(...) :
  conversion failure on 'geziparkı' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <b1>
```

I added the line `pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')` on the top of my script as mentioned in the related previous questions, did not help.

Do I need to change something from my `locale` settings of Ubuntu. My `sessioinInfo()` is following,

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=tr_TR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=tr_TR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=tr_TR.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=tr_TR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C             
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=tr_TR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

PS: I continue investigating this issue, and realized that if I use `.png`, it works perfectly, only problem is with `.pdf`.

Comment: Try installing turkish fonts in pdf viewer.

Comment: @Manish My pdf viewer is ok with other Turkish pdf documents. Are you sure this is the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally found the solution,

Substituting `pdf(file='/home/sait/Desktop/abc.pdf')` with 
`cairo_pdf('/home/sait/Desktop/abc.pdf', family="DejaVu Sans")` did the trick.

I do not know what this actually done, however I have tried a lot of stuff and nothing has worked except this one.

Comment: 3 years later, the only working solution to a similar problem was still this one! In my case I had a `\u25D0` (◐) which would not be printed in plots. The trick seems to be the call to `cario_pdf`; the font family does not seem to have an effect.